# Use of the past for a request?

Tags: tense

In One Punch Man, Genos says ちょっと待った instead of ちょっと待って when asking Saitama to wait. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about using the past form verb 「まった」 in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55379/question-about-using-the-past-form-verb-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-in-this-sentence) / [Difference between ちょっと待って and ちょっと待った](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13428/5010) / [Usage of doubled non-past tense "た"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5356/5010)