# What is the meaning of 「ちょいとまった」?

Tags: words, manga

I think it is came from 「ちょっとまって」and would be alternated by a certain dialect and archaic usage.

I would like to know why the manga character said it in the past tense.

Comment: `why... the past tense`-> This thread might be of help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5356/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be said semi-archaic variant of ちょっと. I've never heard people around me use it unless they want to speak in a jocular way. It's also (stereo-)typically associated with over-middle-age people, older school of delinquent youth or yakuza, or roughly Edo to pre-war period accents in many fictional works.

As for dialects, [online dictionaries on Gunma, Yamanashi, and Wakayama dialects](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8) seem to have this word as headword.

Don't confuse it with nominal suffix -ちょい, which is still in regular use as a more casual variation of nominal suffix -ちょっと "a little over; -odd".

For the "past tense" part, see @chocolate's comment.