# 待った！ as an interjection

Tags: conjugations, colloquial-language, imperatives

I've just noticed that in the 逆転裁判/Ace Attorney series, the interjection translated as "Hold it!" is 「待った！」I would understand if it was 「待って！」, but why would the past tense be used as an interjection? "Waited!" doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: See also: [Usage of doubled non-past tense “た”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5356/5010)